# torch.cuda.is_available() returns false

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I have the following configuration:

```
OS: Windows 10
GCC version: (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)

Python version: 3.7.5
CUDA runtime version: 9.0.176
cuDNN version: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin\cudnn64_7.dll

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip] numpy==1.17.4
[pip] torch==1.1.0
[pip] torch-nightly==1.2.0.dev20190723
[pip] torchfile==0.1.0
[pip] torchvision==0.3.0
[conda] blas                      1.0                         mkl    defaults
[conda] cuda92                    1.0                           0    pytorch
[conda] mkl                       2019.0                   pypi_0    pypi
[conda] mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hb782905_0    defaults
[conda] mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37h14836fe_0    defaults
[conda] mkl_random                1.1.0            py37h675688f_0    defaults
[conda] pytorch                   1.1.0           py3.7_cuda90_cudnn7_1    pytorch
[conda] torch-nightly             1.2.0.dev20190723          pypi_0    pypi
[conda] torchfile                 0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
[conda] torchvision               0.3.0               py37_cu90_1    pytorch
```

And finnaly `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns false. 
I've tried a lot of solutions but could not solve this problem.
 
My graphics card is Nvidia GeForce GT 650M

Comment: you need to install pytorch with the appropriate cuda version. Pytorch doesn't use the systems cuda so make sure you install a version that is compatible with your GPU.

Comment: This might be a driver compatibility issue. Maybe the tables in https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html will help?

Comment: Can you try uninstalling pytorch and torchvision then use `conda install pytorch==1.1.0 torchvision==0.3.0 cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch`?

Comment: Looks like my video card is too old and is no longer supported...

Comment: @Roman I don't think Keplar cards are too old. I've used them just fine with CUDA 9 and CUDA 10 (though not that card in particular). According to the [release notes](http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/425.31/425.31-win10-win8-win7-release-notes.pdf) the [425.31 driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/145874/en-us) supports CUDA 10.1. You probably just need to update the drivers.

Comment: @jodag I'm afraid that the video card is too old https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-cuda-is-available-always-returns-false/66731/3

Comment: Good to know. Good luck building pytorch!